# Attach MSSQL_DB inside yml.file

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose, yaml, containers

I have a project that runs in 3 Containers.

- API-Container
- Project-Container
- MSSQL-Container

Since the Container is running with a new MSSQL database, I need to attach my DB to it.

So the question is, how can I attach it in my yml.file?

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  levsundt.project:
    ports:
      - "32333:80"
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}levsundtproject
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./LevSundt.Project/Dockerfile
    environment:
         "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
         "ConnectionStrings:WebAppUserDbConnection": "Server=db;Database=LevSundtUsers;user id=web;password=webPassw0rd!; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"      
         "LevSundtBaseUrl" : "http://levsundt.api"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - levsundt.api
      
  levsundt.api:
    ports:
      - "32330:80"
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}levsundtapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./LevSundt.Api2/Dockerfile
    environment:
         "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
         "ConnectionStrings:LevSundtDbConnection": "Server=db;Database=LevSundtDomain; user id=api;password=apiPassw0rd!; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    user: root
    ports:
      - "14330:1433"
    environment:
        MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "SqlPassw0rd!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"

    volumes:
      - C:\Temp\SqlVolume\data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - C:\Temp\SqlVolume\log:/var/opt/mssql/log
      - C:\Temp\SqlVolume\secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets 

    container_name: sql2019
    hostname: sql1
```

Comment: What are you overriding mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest's user to be `root`? The image's service user is meant to be the lesser-privileged `mssql` account.

Comment: Would you describe what the problem is with this compose file? What error you get, share with us. Also don't do this: `C:\Temp\SqlVolume\data:/var/opt/mssql/data` mounting from host windows to WSL2 is really bad performance, mount from the WSL2 filesystem. `~/myproject/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data` but you are better off not bind mounting but using docker volumes so your image/container is independent of the host system filesystem: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: The problem is that I want to run my project in a container, but with access to the data I already have in my db. 
So the problem is how to attach the container to that db in at compose file.?